# Fullcalendar arranging events in order of colour

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am implementing Full Calendar for a client of mine who uses it for logging bookings on properties. In theory it works well but the one thing that's been requested is that each property be displayed on a certain line regardless of how many bookings / events are already displayed that day. For example, Property #1 always at the top, Property #10 always at bottom and everything in-between. Properties are determined by colour to make it easier to see.

Here is a screen shot of my calendar currently:

[image]

As you can see, the green strip between the 14th and 17th is at the top because there are no other events on that day, but I want the green strip to be in-line with the green strip on the 18th to the 20th event, so that all green lines are on the same level, as with all other colours.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: the events are placed based on the start time, and, as you've noted, how many other events there are in that block. If you want to separate bookings by each property, you'd need to use the Scheduler plugin I think: https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/ Each property would be a separate "resource" and have its own line in the timeline. You can scale the timeline to longer periods more like the month view you've got above. The only snag is it's a paid enhancement (unless you're a non-profit, but it sounds like that's not the case here).

Comment: I think I may have used the scheduler before - so I'll check it out again. Thanks for your suggestion.